# editing and adding values for a string object using string builder

Tags: java, string, object, stringbuilder

Im very new to programming and im taking a course. It wants me to create a string object using string buider. I think i figured it out `StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(test);`. It makes a string object(i think) with the name test. I wanted to be able to add 'values' inside of it. Like the string object "test" also has like a sub category for like "sub test". I also dont know how I would access and call on those specific values. as  i said before im new so I am probably missing a method or something basic that I can use. Thanks.

The only other thing I could think of that would add two values together is a 2 dim array but the class wants me to use string objects and string builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you showed makes a `StringBuilder` with contents of 'test'.  It isn't a string.  You can get the String value from it by calling `toString()`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("initial value.");
sb.append("test");
sb.append("[sub test]");
String val = sb.toString();
System.out.println(val);
```

Try the code, experiment with it. See what prints.

Comment: Thanks i understand it now